# Custom ErrorMessage for model validation attributes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am new to MVC, so please bear with me.

We have a large `WebForms` website, where content is managed by a
custom CMS. I have added DataAnnotation attributes to my model
properties. The attributes have an `ErrorMessage` property, but this
must be a compile-time constant.

I would like to get error message texts at runtime from out custom
CMS. We already do this in our `WebForms` pages, so the infrustructure
is in place i.e. manager classes with aproprate methods for retrieving
the correct texts by key.

My question is where do I hook in at runtime in order to populate the
texts from the CMS to be displayed when validation error occur
client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I guess would be to create your own [DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider%29;k%28DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). Derive from this class and override the CreateMetadata method. Don't forget to register your custom MetaDataProvider with the ModelMetadataProviders when your WebApp initializes.

Comment: Yep, that`ll do it. DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider was just what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.